How can I do text pre-processing in IBM SPSS Modeler?
I want to do the standard text cleaning of removing stop word, stemming, tokenisation, etc. I think SPSS has limitation but how do people get around with this using SPSS?
Chatgpt said to use python script but i couldnt find it within SPSS and another suggestion was to use derive node to remove stop word? How though?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
